# Passing Array of Values into Inner SQL Server Select Statement in Node Project

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

In my Node batch-processor project I am using the `mssql` package, and I need to gather data from two different SQL databases and then basically emulate a `merge` operation. My question is, for SQL Server, is there a way I can use `IN` to pass in an array of IDs as part of the inner SELECT?

To clarify, the IDs I'll be passing in have been gathered from a separate query from a different SQL database. So what I need to do now is pass those IDs into this next query.

I've seen this kind of syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM Production.Product
WHERE ProductModelID IN
    (SELECT ProductModelID 
     FROM Production.ProductModel AS pm
     WHERE p.ProductModelID = pm.ProductModelID
        AND Name LIKE 'Long-Sleeve Logo Jersey%');
GO
```

What would it look like to pass in those IDs as part of the inner SELECT statement? Is this something that can be done? Or is there a different way I should approach this?

And to clarify, I do need to do this within my Node project - so calling a stored procedure and using linked tables from my SQL Server database is not an option.

By the way, I could do something like this:

```
  getMatchingIdRecords = async function() {
    for (let sourceRecord of sourceArr) {
      const matchingIdRecord = await sqlServerQueryHandler(`SELECT NoteDetailsId FROM SR_Empsheets
      WHERE NoteDetailsId = ${sourceRecord.notes_detail_id}`);
      if (matchingIdRecord) matchingIdRecords.push(matchingIdRecord);
    }
    return matchingIdRecords;
  };
```

But this is less than ideal because I'm basically hitting the database for every record that is iterated through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2016+ you can pass a JSON Array to the query and parse it on the server.  Something like:

```
SELECT NoteDetailsId FROM SR_Empsheets
      WHERE NoteDetailsId in ( select value from openjson(@jsonArray) )
```

Where @jsonArray is a nvarchar(max) parameter that looks like

```
 N'["1323","2311","1234"]'
```

Comment: Good to know! I will double-check what version we're on and will try this. Thanks, @David.